# Different solution of a norway mensa IQ test question

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

I am thinking about this question:

[image]

The public [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89281/mensa-norway-last-3-questions?newreg=85c6cee7ef2643148bc2e91294c47f19) is

> D

But I think I have another working solution, but I wasn't able to find any validation.

I think it's

> **A**
>  [image]
>  The red marked fields added up build the green field. So the whole pattern looks basically like a C. And when we use this pattern to get `?`.
>  [image]
> We end up in **A**.

Did I miss anything or is this also a valid solution?

Comment: As your answer is only based on a "single" observation, usually that might be incorrect. You should justify again with other observations. For example, by taking the third L from the third row (along with your solution) + R1C1 to get R1C3, which in this case, it doesn't match. Thus your solution, unfortunately, might fall into an opinion-based solution and usually it's not the correct one as it can be arbitrary.

Comment: @athin Thanks for your answer. Yes, the "single observation" explanation makes sense.

Comment: Such puzzles are extremely terrible in the first place, because they contain too little information to make the 'official solution' the simplest. Your solution shows this! (So I upvoted.) See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358577/21820) to get a rough idea of how to quantify this notion.